# skip duplicates and filter foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to filter some items that are in a big `.txt` file to only show the ones that match current date. I am able to get it to show items matching the current day, but it seems to also include items before that and it also loops the last entry endlessly.

This is the file I'm working in:

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
    require_once('program.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Oslo");
    $datetime_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $idag = date('Y-m-d');
    $imorgen = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));
// $datetime_now = '2010-01-04 09:29:00';
    $i = 0;
//
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($program);
// echo "</pre>";

    $program = getRadioProgram();

    foreach ($program as $program_na) {
    if ($idag == substr($program_na['datotid'], 0, 10)) {


            if ($i == 0) $j = 0;
            else $j = $i-1;
        // echo "i: ".$i." j: ".$j;

            $program_dato = substr($program[$j]['datotid'], 0, 10);
            $program_tid = substr($program[$j]['datotid'], -8, 5);
            $program_tittel = str_replace('', '&ndash;', shorten($program[$j]['tittel'], 41));
            $program_bilde = get_programImage(utf8_encode($program[$j]['tittel']));
            $programleder = substr($program[$j]['tittel'], strpos($program[$j]['tittel'], " med ") + 0);
            $programbaretittel = explode(" med ",$program[$j]['tittel']);
            $programtittel = $programbaretittel['0'];
            $programspons = $program[$j]['spons'];
        }
?>
<?php echo $program_dato.' - '.$program_tid; ?>
<?php echo $programtittel; ?>
<?php echo $programleder; ?>
<?php
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

This is **program.php** which is included

```
<?php


function getRadioProgram() {
    // open the file, and read the contents

    // if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {

        $attachment = get_attachment_url_by_slug('radioprogram_' . date("Y") . '-' . date("m"));

        if (strpos($attachment[0]->guid, '.txt') === false) {
            $attachment = get_attachment_url_by_slug('radioprogram_' . date("Y") . '-' . date("m") . '-2');
        }

        $filename = get_attached_file($attachment[0]->ID);  

                // 
        // if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        //  var_dump($attachment);
        // }

        // var_dump($filename);
    // } else {
    //  $filename = get_root()."/uploads/radioprogram_" . date("Y") . "-" . date("m") . ".txt";
    // }

    // var_dump($attachment);


    $handle = @fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = @fread($handle, @filesize($filename));
    $contents = utf8_encode($contents);
    @fclose($handle);

    // manipulate the contents
    $contents = explode("\n", $contents);

    $ukedager = array("MANDAG", "TIRSDAG", "ONSDAG", "TORSDAG", "FREDAG", "LØRDAG", "SØNDAG");
    $maneder = array("JANUAR", "FEBRUAR", "MARS", "APRIL", "MAI", "JUNI", "JULI", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OKTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DESEMBER");

    $i = 0;
    $num_days = 0;
    $program = array();

    foreach ($contents as $val) {
        if (strlen($val) < 2) $val = rtrim($val);
        else $val = ltrim($val);

        if (empty($val)) continue; // skip empty lines
        //if ((stripos($val, "Nyheter ") !== false) OR stripos($val, "Pluss ") !== false) continue; // skip lines starting with ...

        $val_small = substr($val, 0, 9);

        $is_day = false;

        $j = 0;

        foreach ($ukedager AS $ukedag) { // loop through week days
            if (strpos($val_small, $ukedag) !== false) {
                $val = trim(strstr($val, " "))."\n";

                $val = str_replace("   ", " ", $val);
                $val = str_replace("  ", " ", $val);            

                $date =  explode(" ", $val);

                $day = str_replace(".", "", $date[0]);
                $month = trim($date[1]);
                $year = trim($date[2]);

                if ($day < 10) {
                    $day = "0".$day;
                }

                $k = 0;

                for ($k=0;$k<=11;$k++) {
                    if ($maneder[$k] == $month) {
                        $month_number = $k+1;

                        if ($month_number < 10) {
                            $month_number = "0".$month_number;
                        }
                    }
                }           
                $num_days++;
                $is_day = true;
            }

            $j++;
        }

        // finn klokkeslett og tittel
        if (is_numeric($val{0})) {  
            $klokkeslett = substr($val, 0, 5);
            $tittel = trim(substr($val, 6));            
            $tittel = str_replace("å", "&aring;", $tittel);
            $tittel = str_replace("ø", "&oslash;", $tittel);
            $tittel = str_replace("–", "&dash;", $tittel);
            $tittel = explode("- Sponsor:", $tittel);

            if (!strpos($klokkeslett, " ")) {   
                $klokkeslett = explode(".", $klokkeslett);

                if ($klokkeslett[0] == "01") $day++; // hack, might not work

                $date_final = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime($klokkeslett[0], $klokkeslett[1], 0, $month_number, $day, $year));         

                $program[$i]["datotid"] = $date_final;
                $program[$i]["tittel"] = $tittel[0];
                $program[$i]["spons"] = $tittel[1];

            }
        }

        $i++;
    }

    sort($program);

    return $program;
}
$program = getRadioProgram();
?>
```

This is a part of the text file:

```
TIRSDAG  28. JUNI  2016 <- date
Radio 102 AS har innholdskonsesjon og sendeanleggskonsesjon for 24/7-radio i konsesjonsområde 11-01 (Haugesund m.fl.) på sendenett 11-01.0. Stasjonen sender, i henhold til konsesjonsvilkårene,  376 minutter lokalt innhold i døgnet. Konsesjonen er gitt med en varighet fra 1. Januar 2010 til 31. Desember 2016. Radio 102 AS oppfyller Medietilsynets minstekrav til kompetanse innen radiodrift, økonomiske driftsforutsetninger og lokalt innhold. <- unnecessary information

Nyheter hver hele time fra 6.00 til 18.00 <-likewise

Time    Program title med(with) host (L= local programme)
06.00   Din morgen med Eivind og Helge (L)
09.00   Formiddag med Hanne (L)
12.00   Lunsj med Egil (L)
15.00   Ettermiddagsrush med Monica (L)
18.00   Max musikk med Hanne (L) 
20.00   Max musikk med Monica (L)
22.00   Mot midnatt – de beste balladene på 102 (L)  
24.00   Neon, 102-musikk hele natta! (til 08.00)



TIRSDAG  31. MAI 2016
Radio 102 AS har innholdskonsesjon og sendeanleggskonsesjon for 24/7-radio i konsesjonsområde 11-01 (Haugesund m.fl.) på sendenett 11-01.0. Stasjonen sender, i henhold til konsesjonsvilkårene,  376 minutter lokalt innhold i døgnet. Konsesjonen er gitt med en varighet fra 1. Januar 2010 til 31. Desember 2016. Radio 102 AS oppfyller Medietilsynets minstekrav til kompetanse innen radiodrift, økonomiske driftsforutsetninger og lokalt innhold.

Nyheter hver hele time fra 6.00 til 18.00

06.00         Din morgen med Eivind Thor Magnar og Helge (L)
09.00   Formiddag med Hanne  (L)
12.00   Lunsj med Egil (L)
15.00   Ettermiddagsrush med Monica (L) 
18.00   Max musikk med Hanne (L)
20.00   Max musikk med Monica (L) 
22.00   Mot midnatt – de beste balladene på 102 (L)
24.00   Neon, 102-musikk hele natta! (til 06.00)



ONSDAG  1. JUNI  2016
Radio 102 AS har innholdskonsesjon og sendeanleggskonsesjon for 24/7-radio i konsesjonsområde 11-01 (Haugesund m.fl.) på sendenett 11-01.0. Stasjonen sender, i henhold til konsesjonsvilkårene,  376 minutter lokalt innhold i døgnet. Konsesjonen er gitt med en varighet fra 1. Januar 2010 til 31. Desember 2016. Radio 102 AS oppfyller Medietilsynets minstekrav til kompetanse innen radiodrift, økonomiske driftsforutsetninger og lokalt innhold.

Nyheter hver hele time fra 6.00 til 18.00

06.00   Din morgen med Eivind, Thor Magnar og Helge (L)
09.00   Formiddag med Hanne (L)
12.00   Lunsj med Monica (L)
15.00   Ettermiddagsrush med Egil (L)
18.00   Max musikk med Hanne (L) 
20.00   Max musikk med Monica (L)
22.00   Mot midnatt – de beste balladene på 102 (L)    
24.00   Neon, 102-musikk hele natta! (til 06.00)
```

This is a part of an old script which was previously only to show the item matching the current time. The plan is to make it only show items matching `$idag` and then to be able to filter it to only show items matching `$imorgen` and so on.

I have tried different variations of the `foreach` skips, but I'm confused in which I'm supposed to put it before. A cleanup of the code would probarbly also be a good thing.

Comment: It would help to see a few lines of the text file to see how it's formatted.

Comment: Included some bit of the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking to do:

```
// Create a function for array mapping
// Note that my regex abilities are not great, so I can guarantee
// someone else can do it to where this portion is not necessary
function filterEmpty($v)
    {
        $v =   trim($v);
            return $v;
    }

function getDatesFromFile($filename)
    {
        // Set the file to an array
        $getFile   =   file(__DIR__.$filename,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        // Pre-assign some variables
        $new       =   
        $arr       =   array();
        $year      =   
        $mo            =   
        $day       =   false;
        // Set today
        $today     =   date('Y-n-j');
        // Set tomorrow
        $tommorow  =   date("Y-n-j", strtotime("+1 day"));
        // Set all the months in the year
        $calendar  =   array(
                            "JANUAR",
                            "FEBRUAR",
                            "MARS",
                            "APRIL",
                            "MAI",
                            "JUNI",
                            "JULI",
                            "AUGUST",
                            "SEPTEMBER",
                            "OKTOBER",
                            "NOVEMBER",
                            "DESEMBER"
                        );
        // Loop through the file array
        foreach($getFile as $key => $line) {
            // Trim the line
            $line  =   trim($line);
            // If empty, skip
            if(empty($line))
                continue;
            // Match the trimmed line for this line: TIRSDAG  28. JUNI  2016 
            $regex      =   '/^([^\s|^\t]{1,})([\s|\t]{1,})([\d]{1,})\.([\s]{1,})([^\t]{1,})([\d]{4})/i';
            $section    =   preg_match($regex,$line,$match);

            if($section) {
                $mo     =   trim($match[5]);
                $mo     =   array_search($mo,$calendar)+1;
                $isDate =   $match[6].'-'.$mo.'-'.$match[3];
            }

            if(!isset($isDate))
                continue;
            elseif(($isDate != $today) && ($isDate != $tommorow))
                continue;

            if(!isset($new[$isDate]))
                $new[$isDate]   =   array();

            // If array is set, go through the sub-set data
            if(preg_match('/^([0-9\.]{4}).*/',$line)) {
                // Again, someone could do this better, I'm sure
                preg_match('/^([\d\.]{5})([^a-zA-Z]{1,})(.+)/i',$line,$details);
                $details   =   array_filter(array_map('filterEmpty',$details));
                unset($details[0]);
                $details   =   array_values($details);

                if(strpos($details[1],' med ') !== false)
                    $hosted     =   explode(' med ',$details[1]);
                elseif(strpos($details[1],'-') !== false)
                    $hosted     =   explode('-',$details[1]);
                elseif(strpos($details[1],'–') !== false)
                    $hosted     =   explode('–',$details[1]);

                $hosted =   array_filter(array_map('filterEmpty',$hosted));

                $new[$isDate][substr($details[0],0,2)]    =   $hosted;
            }
        }

        return $new;
    }

$programs   =   getDatesFromFile('/test.txt');

foreach($programs as $y => $yearRow) {
    echo '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($yearRow as $time => $pData) {
        echo '<li><div>'.number_format($time,2).'</div><div>'.implode('</div><div>',$pData).'</div></li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**`$programs` gives you this array:**

```
Array
(
    [2016-6-3] => Array
        (
            [06] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Din morgen
                    [1] => Eivind og Helge (L)
                )

            [09] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Formiddag
                    [1] => Hanne (L)
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lunsj
                    [1] => Egil (L)
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Ettermiddagsrush
                    [1] => Monica (L)
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Max musikk
                    [1] => Hanne (L)
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Max musikk
                    [1] => Monica (L)
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mot midnatt
                    [1] => de beste balladene på 102 (L)
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Neon, 102
                    [1] => musikk hele natta! (til 08.00)
                )

        )

    [2016-6-2] => Array
        (
            [06] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Din morgen
                    [1] => Eivind, Thor Magnar og Helge (L)
                )

            [09] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Formiddag
                    [1] => Hanne (L)
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lunsj
                    [1] => Monica (L)
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Ettermiddagsrush
                    [1] => Egil (L)
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Max musikk
                    [1] => Hanne (L)
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Max musikk
                    [1] => Monica (L)
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mot midnatt
                    [1] => de beste balladene på 102 (L)
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Neon, 102
                    [1] => musikk hele natta! (til 06.00)
                )

        )

)
```

Gives you HTML (you'd have to do some formatting):

```
<ul>
<li><div>6.00</div><div>Din morgen</div><div>Eivind og Helge (L)</div></li>
<li><div>9.00</div><div>Formiddag</div><div>Hanne (L)</div></li>
<li><div>12.00</div><div>Lunsj</div><div>Egil (L)</div></li>
<li><div>15.00</div><div>Ettermiddagsrush</div><div>Monica (L)</div></li>
<li><div>18.00</div><div>Max musikk</div><div>Hanne (L)</div></li>
<li><div>20.00</div><div>Max musikk</div><div>Monica (L)</div></li>
<li><div>22.00</div><div>Mot midnatt</div><div>de beste balladene på 102 (L)</div></li>
<li><div>24.00</div><div>Neon, 102</div><div>musikk hele natta! (til 08.00)</div></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><div>6.00</div><div>Din morgen</div><div>Eivind, Thor Magnar og Helge (L)</div></li>
<li><div>9.00</div><div>Formiddag</div><div>Hanne (L)</div></li>
<li><div>12.00</div><div>Lunsj</div><div>Monica (L)</div></li>
<li><div>15.00</div><div>Ettermiddagsrush</div><div>Egil (L)</div></li>
<li><div>18.00</div><div>Max musikk</div><div>Hanne (L)</div></li>
<li><div>20.00</div><div>Max musikk</div><div>Monica (L)</div></li>
<li><div>22.00</div><div>Mot midnatt</div><div>de beste balladene på 102 (L)</div></li>
<li><div>24.00</div><div>Neon, 102</div><div>musikk hele natta! (til 06.00)</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for some cleanup. But which of the $'s should I use If I want to create some variables to insert into echo? I'm using the edited version. I can get it to print all of the arrays if I set it to print_r($new[$today]);

Comment: What do you want to echo?

Comment: I thought you were mainly wanting to extract the two relevant days based on today's date and tomorrow's date? Are you wanting to be able to echo the `06`-`24` values?

Comment: If you look at the code from my first item, you see that I have put some of the items from the array into different variables which I then echo inside some divs. I will look around for the solution as well. I am able now to expand the code to be able to show the next 7 days with print_r.

Comment: Ok that is doable, but I don't know what that comes from, it's hard to follow your script without using google translate to figure out what your keys and stuff are named and derived from. Where are you deriving data from to make those divs and I can easily modify the script.

Comment: I see. Updated the original post with some translated markers.

Comment: Are you splitting something like this up `Din morgen med Eivind og Helge` into `Din morgen` and `Eivind og Helge`?

Comment: Yep, and the numbers 06.00 and so forth are scheduled time for the shows. It's a schedule I'm trying to convert from .txt to fancy divs in a php.

Comment: Ok, give me one second to revise, it's pretty easy.

Comment: Alright take a look, you can see where I modified to break up the lines. You can just edit those portions to finesse the table layout

Comment: Nice. Thanks. How would I go about making a different foreach loop for each day.

Comment: I did that. Each `<ul>` in the script is a day

Comment: What I mean is to have it like this

`<div>TUESDAY</div>
<ul>...
</ul>
<div>WEDNESDAY</div>
<ul>...`
To run a foreach loop in a separate place. With the print_r I was able to only output items matching $today or $tomorrow. How can I get different foreach loops to match $today, $tomorrow and so forth? I see no specification in the last two foreach loops you have provided.

Comment: In the first loop, the date is the `$y`, you can just convert that back to the day using `strtotime()` and `date()`. `$y` is the `2016-6-3` and `2016-6-2`

Comment: Ah, ok. I will look into it. Thank you so much for helping me out, Rasclatt

Comment: No problem. If you think I helped don't be shy about marking the question answered. ;)

Comment: I have tried now to find out a way to make it break the foreach loop after the first day and then have tried to insert a new foreach loop after specifiying that I want the next day. But I either get an infinite loop of the first day or it only shows the first day.

[link](http://kickasspastes.com/29713/)
Working example: [link](http://www.va24.no/wp-content/themes/discussionwp/lyttesenterprogramdagarray.php)

Comment: Did you use my script for that?

Comment: I was trying to filter it with the script you provided. You said $y is the date and I tried to make it like this. I was thinking I might should include an if. If $y is $tomorrow then run the foreach loop.

Comment: Well `$y` is in the loop, as the day, then under that day, the times, so are you trying to separate out the two days so you can manually do the days in different spots or something or what are you trying to do? Are you trying to have two variables each being an array, day 1 and day 2?

Comment: Exactly. That is the main purpose of this whole thing. To be able to show the different days in different spots. Right now it's just a test to get it to show Today's shows below TODAY and Tomorrow's shows below TOMORROW. I have expanded the code to seven days to make it show the next seven days.

Comment: Ok, well that comes down to design, you can create the whole layout in the loop using `if/else` and `CSS`. If you have to take the days and move them into spots that you can not do using `CSS` manipulation, then you can you create keys like `$key = date('Y-n-j'); $todayArr = $programs[$key];` then assign others how you please. What I have is the building block, I don't know how you want to layout your page, but you can technically build the whole page just in the one loop.

Comment: As you can see in my first post. I have several $var for each element in the .txt. This is the layout I'm thinking if you take account into what it is in the first post: [http://kickasspastes.com/29738/](http://kickasspastes.com/29738/)

Comment: @skoen based on that link, that is pretty much what I have, I just have different html. You just have to change the html in the loop

Comment: But it doesn't change the fact that right now it seems to loop the same day several times, and it does not appear to fetch the right information for friday june 3rd, which is today.

[http://www.va24.no/wp-content/themes/discussionwp/lyttesenterprogramdagarray.php](http://www.va24.no/wp-content/themes/discussionwp/lyttesenterprogramdagarray.php) - [source](http://kickasspastes.com/29832/)

It's also still showing Thursday, when it's clearly Friday.

Comment: How can I change the code for the for loops to make them show **ONLY** the day I want? Which is the main purpose of this whole thread.

Comment: It would a lot easier to take a look at the actual page and see everything you're trying to do. If you have a guest ftp I can take a look at it live

Comment: I don't have access give you guest ftp. But if you can somehow drop me your email I will be able to provide you with access and directions to where you can find the file. As I said, it's currently in a proof state to see if it works. If it works, then CSS styling will be added. Right now it's not working as it should.

Comment: You've got mail :)

Comment: I am sorry for refreshing this very old post, but right now I'm trying to reuse this code for a different, but maybe simpler text file, but I'm still having some issues. The new textfile (schedule) contains some shows that are only 30 minutes long, meaning they both start at the same hour, but different minute. And I don't need a «host» field, just want to echo the programtitle. I haved tried altering the code, but I end up with lots of errors: https://radiol.no/wp-content/themes/virtus-child/sendeplantest.php

Comment: Text file is located at: https://radiol.no/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sendeplan-07.txt